# What are the pros/cons of installing glass doors over a whirlpool tub?

Tags: bathroom, shower

I'm building a new bathroom and I have a whirlpool tub. I really like the tile behind it, and I would like the look and the feel of being able to see through wall to wall. However, I'm worried about 2 specific things, and whatever other issues you guys may be able to inform me of. First, comfort of trying to relax in a whirlpool tub with a metal guide right there. Is that going to be annoying?

Second - I'm worried about the vibrations of the air jets somehow effecting the glass.

Anything else I'm missing in weighing this decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metal guide track is only annoying if you really don't like the looks. that is a personal thing, but every tub with doors has one and millions of people live with it.  The vibration from the jets will not adversely effect the glass doors at all, especially if you select a quality door unit. I prefer to install suspended type doors like the Kholer or Sterling. They suspend all the weight from the overhead bar so there is no weight on the bottom guide. they operate very smoothly and are easy to keep clean, especially the ones with treated glass.